# Laravel Where Between Dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table which gathers simple datetime in and datetime out for a user.

I'm using laravel to output the rows where indate_time is between specific date range.

```
From Date: 2016/01/28
To Date: 2016/01/28
```

Sample entry in my table

```
ID | indate_time          | outdate_time
1  | 2016-01-28 21:22:49  | 2016-01-28 21:46:05
```

At the moment Im getting no response here's my laravel query

```
$from = '2016/01/28';
$to = '2016/01/28';
$id = 1;

        $attendance = DB::table('attendances')
        ->whereBetween('indate_time', array($from, $to))->where('id', $id)->orderBy('indate_time', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: your new datetime will get `2016-01-28 00:00:00` so how can `indate_time` be between that and the same?

Comment: you're comparing datetime values, not just dates. if all you're concerned about is the dates, then you need to explicitly tell mysql that. because `2016-01-28 23:59:59` is the same date, but outside of the specific time range.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB how would I specify date out of datetime for the laravel query? Sorry

Comment: `$from  = new \DateTime("now"); $to = new \DateTime("now");
$to->setTime(23, 59, 59);`

Answer (score 0):

Can i recommend you using Carbon then you can do something like this:

In your model

```
public function getDaysUntilDeadlineAttribute()
{   
    return Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->diffInDays($this->outdate_time, false); // if you are past your deadline, the value returned will be negative.  
}
```

And then in your view:

```
$model->days_until_deadline
```

Remeber to include `use Carbon;` at the top

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are comparing the dates with wrong format.

Your dates are as follows

```
$from = '2016/01/28';
$to = '2016/01/28';
```

The date formats  in db are

```
 ID | indate_time          | outdate_time
 1  | 2016-01-28 21:22:49  | 2016-01-28 21:46:05
```

Now simply just change the $from and $to date formats to

```
 $from = '2016-01-28 12:14:07';
 $to = '2016-01-28 09:03:23';
```

now you can write the query with above values.

If any rows matched those will be displayed.